# How to extract digit in image that overide rect area

Tags: opencv, image-processing, convex-hull

Now, I have a project that use image processing about detect digit but I don't know how to extract when digit override the rect area.

Here's the input:

[image]

I want to get something like the bottom pictures:

[image]

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail, with any code that you have already tried. Also, please be more specific regarding the tags. Your tags methion three things that usually DO NOT go together.

Comment: sorry,i don't have code now.i want to know the algorithm .and i want to show the  picture but i can't upload in stack overflow.now i updated question already.please check

Comment: Is it compulsory for you to use OpenCV?

Comment: i think no.but i don't know image library that use in android anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digits can be extracted using OpenCV using the concept of contours. The following implementation is in Python.

Go through the following steps:

- Convert your image to gray-scale
- Apply appropriate threshold so that the digits are in white while everything else is in black.
- Now find contours. Since you have small stars they will also get picked up. To avoid picking them up pass a suitable area above which contours must be found.
- Compute the convex hull for each contour and mask them on the original image.

You need to work with individual convex hull after extracting the contours.

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\2_new.jpg', 1)
img2 = img.copy()
cv2.imshow("original.jpg", img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, threshed_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#--- Black image to be used to draw individual convex hull ---
black = np.zeros_like(img)
#cv2.imshow("black.jpg", black)

contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0]) #added by OP : this sorts contours left to right, so images come in order

for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 200:
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

        black2 = black.copy()

        #--- Here is where I am filling the contour after finding the convex hull ---
        cv2.drawContours(black2, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        g2 = cv2.cvtColor(black2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, t2 = cv2.threshold(g2, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow("t2.jpg", t2)

        masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask = t2)    
        cv2.imshow("masked.jpg", masked)

        print(len(hull))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You should be able to get something like the following:

[image]

[image]